# Open Rear camera in QR Code Reader for Mobile Website

Tags: android, iphone, qr-code, webcam.js

Hi got following code from [sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-qr-code-reader-mobile-website/):

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body, input {font-size:14pt}
input, label {vertical-align:middle}
.qrcode-text {padding-right:1.7em; margin-right:0}
.qrcode-text-btn {display:inline-block; background:url(//dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1499401426qr_icon.svg) 50% 50% no-repeat; height:1em; width:1.7em; margin-left:-1.7em; cursor:pointer}
.qrcode-text-btn > input[type=file] {position:absolute; overflow:hidden; width:1px; height:1px; opacity:0}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type=text size=16 placeholder="Tracking Code" class=qrcode-text>
        <label class=qrcode-text-btn><input type=file accept="image/*" capture=environment onclick="return showQRIntro();" onchange="openQRCamera(this);" tabindex=-1></label> 
        <input type=button value="Go" disabled>
        <script src="qr_packed.js"></script>
        <script>
            function openQRCamera(node) {
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function() {
                node.value = "";
                qrcode.callback = function(res) {
                  if(res instanceof Error) {
                    alert("No QR code found. Please make sure the QR code is within the camera's frame and try again.");
                  } else {
                    node.parentNode.previousElementSibling.value = res;
                  }
                };
                qrcode.decode(reader.result);
              };
              reader.readAsDataURL(node.files[0]);
            }

            function showQRIntro() {
              return confirm("Use your camera to take a picture of a QR code.");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this code on click of QR icon Mobile camera is opened. But I want to open camera on page lode in specified area of web page. My screen design is below:
[image]

My requirement is below:

- By default mobile camera or webcam in PC/laptop should open and start scanning. After scanning the code should display in input box.
- On click of QR icon file upload opens, after QR image upload, the code appears in input box
- OR user can type/copy paste QR code received in the input box.

I've create one code after modifying [webqr.com](https://webqr.com/) which is working fine on desktop/ laptop and android device but camera is not opening in ios device and macbook.

Hence I searched and found above code which is able to open camera in iphone and ipad. But have no idea how to achieve my above mentioned requirement.